# Google Drive sharing dialog blocked by x-frame-options, sameorigin

Tags: google-drive-api

I can not get the Share dialog to work for the life of me.  I created a test page here: https://super.neutrondrive.com/edit?view=test

What am I doing wrong that I keep getting blocked by xframe?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was I needed to have the app installed on the user's Google Drive. When using the backend api this is pretty easy to do, but when using the JS API this is not readily apparent.